# How to center a Kendo Window?

Tags: jquery, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Trying to move the kendo window to center. If I use myModal.center().open(), somehow it moves it a bit lower and right from center. If I use position: { left: "50%", top: "60%" }, it does centers it but just for this particular screen. When I use the same control used at other windows, It is not in center. Any other option to center this freaking window?

Comment: please post your markup and code and maybe create a dojo/jsfiddle that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a resembling issues with Kendo Window. I used Kendo Window Activate event to center the window.

```
 .Events(eve => eve.Activate("centerKendoWindow"))
```

Event :

```
function centerKendoWindow(e) {
        this.center();
    }
```

If you are using Kendo Grid inside Kendo Window then you have to make sure that centerKendoWindow() dose not fire before the data is bound to the grid.

if this is the case then you can use Kendo Grid DataBound event to center the window.

Grid DataBound Event

```
 .Events(eve => eve.DataBound("onDataBound"))
```

Center Kendo Window

```
 function onDataBound(args) {
        var grid = $("#kendoaccountgridwindow").data("kendoWindow");
        grid.center();
}
```

Comment: I'm using the MVC wrappers but have to load content for one window with an ajax call. The window is centered initially, but it doesn't adjust when the content actually loads. I used this to fix that problem, but the `refresh` event is the one that fires when the content is fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You can either switch the order, as in:

```
.open().center();
```

Or, what I do, is bind to the open event, like so:

```
$('#my-window').kendoWindow({
    open: function () {
        this.center();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function showDetails(e) {
            var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
            wnd.content(detailsTemplate(dataItem));
            // Use below line to center a kendo window
            wnd.center().open();
        }
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32459448)